# How to install wiimote library in Visual C# Express Edition

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wii, wiimote

I am very new to Visual C# and can't figure out how to install the wiimote library. Can someone tell me how to do so.

Comment: "The Wiimote library" is not something that's out-of-the-box with C# development tools and isn't necessarily well-known, so could you provide a link to clarify what you're talking about and give a few examples of what you've tried?

Comment: @nlawalker heres a link about what I am talking about: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/coding4fun/archive/2007/03/14/1879033.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the dll.

In the project you want to use the library in open the Solution Explorer. Expand it until you see something like:

```
Solution 'MyApplication' (1 project)
-  MyApplication
   + Properties
   + References
   + ...
```

Right click on the References section, select "Add Reference..." then change to the Browse tab. Browse to the folder where you've installed the wiimote library and select the dll. Click "OK" and you should be done.

Comment: What is the references secion? Where do I find it.